# multi tornado websocket block one another

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, tornado

all. 
In my project,I built two websocket connections. one is used for sending pictures from server to client, and the other is used for sending some control data from client to server. now I use only one client.

```
var ws2 = new WebSocket('ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:9002/control')
var ws1 = new WebSocket('ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:9002/data')
ws.binaryType = 'blob'
ws2.onopen =()=> console.log('ws2 connected.')
```

On the server side, once ws1 is open, it constently send data to the client. q is a global queue from which I get the data. This part works fine.
The problem is that the program can not run into on_message(self, message) in function in ws2 after I send message from the client side.

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")

class myWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True;

    def open(self):
    print "websocket1 open."
    while self.ws_connection is not None:
        print "send..."
        try:
            self.write_message(q.get(),True)
        except tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError:
            self.close()
    def on_message(self, message):
        print("websocket1 received message.")
        print message
    def on_close(self):
        print("websocket1 closed.")

class controlWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True;
    def open(self):
        print "websocket2 open"

    def on_message(self, message):
        print("websocket2 received message.")
        print message

    def on_close(self):
        print("websocket2 closed.")
```

and I am sure the client successfully send the control data by click a button.

```
<script>
    function test(){
    ws2.send("this is from ws2.")
    alert("home clicked.")
    }
</script>
```

and I also found that once the open function in ws1 stopped, the ws2 can receive the message. I don't understand why ws1 sending data caused ws2 unable to receive data.

I'm new in python programming and tornado websocket. anyone can help on this problem, thanks a lot~!

Answer (score 0):

Tornado is built on [non-blocking concurrency](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html). This means you must generally avoid blocking methods (or run them in a thread pool). `q.get()` is a blocking method, so nothing else in Tornado can run while it is waiting for a message. You should probably replace this queue with a `tornado.queues.Queue`.

Comment: thanks for your reply and explaination. Now I understand it. thank you very much.